# Unable to use module in local folder

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to create an API wrapper but I am unable to use the wrapper. My `__init__.py`

```
from .sb import Skyblock
```

The folder that contains the module is called `skyblock` and the file with the Skyblock class is called `sb.py`

The file I'm trying to use the module in contains this code

```
from skyblock import *

set_api_key('49baa0d9-ecf3-430d-8669-c08495664889')
uuid = uname_resolver('Metasploitable')
print(get_news())
```

I am getting an undefined error

Here's the directory structure

```
C:.
|   requirements.txt
|   testing.py
|
\---skyblock
    |   sb.py
    |   __init__.py
    |
    \---__pycache__
            sb.cpython-37.pyc
            __init__.cpython-37.pyc
```

Comment: can you ```apt-get install tree``` and paste the structure of your project?

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Comment: Assuming skyblock is your project root directory, can you now ```export PYTHONPATH="C://skyblock"``` making sure the directory is the root directory of your project. Let me know if this works!

Comment: After that your import statement should be: ```from skyblock import sb```

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative import, so you need to import as

```
from .skyblock import *
```

You can refer to this site for more information: [PEP-328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision)